# Highcharts: Dynamically change the offset of the xAxis

Tags: svg, highcharts

I'm working with a column chart whereby I have both positive and negative values. I can't find a way to position the xAxis to the center of the chart container.

[image]

I Would like the xAxis to be in the center, that is at the value y=0

Is there any workaround? I tried to use the `offset` option of the `xAxis` property but I don't now what value to put there. I even tried to use the `load` event to get the chartHeight and divide it by 2, but again the result is not what I expect it to be.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use plugin for that: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/6/Crossing-Specific-Values

Or call `axis.update({ offset: newOffset})` with calculated new offset.

Comment: I've tried updating the axis, but the thing is that I don't know the value of the newOffset.

Comment: There is something i don't understand about the library. In this example, http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/jsCJF/light/ I have negative values, as well. But as you can notice, I set the value of crossing to 10 to make it work. Do you know why it doesn't work for crossing=0

Comment: Yes, you have negative values, but are cut of - since you have set min and max for axes. For example crossing set to 0, see: http://jsfiddle.net/jsCJF/32/

Comment: sorry, I posted the wrong link. I was referring to this example http://jsfiddle.net/jsCJF/33/

Comment: Looks like plugin requires opposite xAxis to bet set, see: http://jsfiddle.net/jsCJF/34/

Comment: Thanks for your help.The thing is that I don't want to set the opposite property to true. So I created a new plugin to fix my problem, see: http://jsfiddle.net/cBr88/2/